# What type is NSString and how many bytes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am new to objective c. Trying to find out the type of NSString in Objective C. I use the sizeof() method from C and lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding method using UTF8 encoding from NSString.

```
NSString *test=@"a";

NSLog(@"LengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: %lu bytes", [test lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

printf("NSString: %lu\n", sizeof(test));
```

This is gonna give me in Console

**LengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: 1 bytes**
and **NSString: 8 bytes**

What is the difference between the two results?
Why LengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns 1 bytes and sizeof method returns 8 bytes?
What is the type of NSString? Int, float, long, long double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of bytes gives you the length of text content using the specified encoding. In this case the string contains a single character, which in UTF8 is encoded as 1 byte.

The `sizeof` gives you the size of the variable's type, which, in this case is a pointer to `NSString`. The size of all pointers on 64bit architectures is 8 bytes. It's essentially the size of memory address, where `NSString` data is stored. `sizeof` is not a method and it's not even a function. It's an operator. The result is known at compile-time.

In other words:

1. The actual string contents are stored in memory in a format that is opaque and shouldn't interest you.
2. On another place in memory, there is `NSString` data structure that contains a pointer to the contents. You can get the size of this structure using `sizeof(NSString)` (actually the size will differ depending on concrete `NSString` subclass, e.g. `NSMutableString`, `NSPlaceholderString` etc).
3. Your variable contains a pointer to `NSString`, that is, its size is `sizeof(NSString*)`, which is always 8 bytes.

`sizeof` operator shouldn't interest you much in Objective-C, unless you are dealing with pointer arithmetics, which should be rather rare.

Comment: So NSString uses in the memory 8 bytes as a variable. The length of text content using the specified encoding has nothing to do with memory?

Comment: @stefanosn Pointer to NSString uses 8 bytes. That's a very different thing.

Comment: I have read your updated answer. So total we have the string contents which is 1 byte and the NSString pointer variable which has a size of memory address 8 bytes. So total in memory we have 9 bytes? Sorry if i am asking silly questions i am just trying to figure it out how it works...

Comment: @stefanosn No, you have a 8 byte pointer, which is a memory address. On that memory address there is `NSString` data structure (or the actual subclass of `NSString`) which contains a lot of data (e.g. its type, reference counter) and between that data there is pointer (again, 8 byte) to an internal buffer which contains the actual data. That buffer doesn't have to be UTF8 encoded, it can be larger that the data it stores and there can be actually multiple buffers in a complex linked data structure. `NSString` is probably not the best example to introduce you to pointers.

Comment: In total, the memory will be *at least* `sizeof(NSString*) + sizeof(NSString) + 1`. Everything else is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining to me. I understand NSString is not the best example to pointers but i see it all the time in objective c projects so i needed to understand in real situations. I do not see in  objective c projects int variables or float variables or char variables...any idea why is that? I mean why NSString is used instead of char variable?

Comment: @stefanosn Multiple reasons. You will rarely see an `int` because the size of `int` is very loosely defined in C. You will rather see typedefs like `NSInteger` which has an exact size definition. There is no reason why you wouldn't see floats or doubles, although you will see `CGFloat` in UI code. `char` will be used for representation of one `byte` but for strings you will see things like `unichar` (a 2 byte UTF16 character) instead. The primitive types in C are pretty complex.

Comment: A null-terminated `char` array commonly used in C to represent strings doesn't even contain the length of that string. Using it for anything is too difficult (not even talking about mutating it, e.g. inserting a character in the middle). The whole concept of Objective-C was an object layer that will simplify things.

Comment: So NSString is an object if i understand correctly.

Comment: @stefanosn Most things are an object in Objective-C. Even primitive types like `NSInteger` can be represented by `NSNumber` which is an object.